# How to improve the performance of data stream insert into Bigquery table in C#

Tags: google-bigquery

I am using C# .Net client library to stream insert data from local file to Bigquery database.I insert all of the data successfully with my code, however, the performance(the insertion speed) is very slow. I am having 20KB/sec loading speed. For instance, I had a file with size 323MB, and the program needs around 20 minutes to load.I tested my bandwidth, the upload speed is like 3MB/sec I was wondering if there is a way to improve the performance?(I suppose it should be much faster than that)

Here is my code:

```
namespace BigQuery_Test
{
    class StreamDatacs
    {


        private static ServiceAccountCredential credential;

        public StreamDatacs()
        {
            Credential2().Wait();


        }

        public async Task Credential2()
        {
            string certificateFile = "C:\\xxxxxx.p12";
            string serviceAccountEmail = "xxxxxxxxxxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com";
            var certificate = new X509Certificate2(certificateFile, "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
            credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
               new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
               {
                   Scopes = new[] { StorageService.Scope.DevstorageReadWrite,
                   BigqueryService.Scope.Bigquery }
               }.FromCertificate(certificate));

            Console.WriteLine(credential.Token);
            Console.WriteLine(credential.TokenServerUrl);
        }
        public void ReadData(string path)        
        {

            var logs = new List<TableDataInsertAllRequest.RowsData>();
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path))
            {
                string line = "";
                string [] aLog = new string[1000];

                Log Loga = new Log();
                int count = 0;
                int i = 0;
                while((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    var theLog = new TableDataInsertAllRequest.RowsData();              
                    string[] token = line.Split('\t');
                    theLog.Json = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                    theLog.Json.Add("Timestamp", token[0]);
                    theLog.Json.Add("ClientIpAddress", token[1]);
                    theLog.Json.Add("Username", token[2]);
                    theLog.Json.Add("GroupID", token[3]);
                    theLog.Json.Add("CompanyID", token[4]);
                    theLog.Json.Add("FullOrSiteLogging", token[5]);
                    theLog.Json.Add("PolicyFlags", token[6]);
                    theLog.Json.Add("ActionsTaken", token[7]);
                    theLog.Json.Add("ResponseStatus", token[8]);                       
                    logs.Add(theLog);
                    count++;

                    if (count > 20000)
                    {

                        BQStreamInsert(logs);
                        logs.Clear();
                        count = 0;

                    }
                }

            }

            Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
        }
        public void BQStreamInsert(List<TableDataInsertAllRequest.RowsData> rows)
        {
            string projectId= "ws-2015-logs";
            string datasetId = "CompanyGroup1";
            string tableId ="RawLogsTest7";
            var service = new BigqueryService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,

                ApplicationName = "BQ test"
            });
            try
            {
                var content = new TableDataInsertAllRequest();
                content.Rows = rows;
                content.Kind = "bigquery#tableDataInsertAllRequest";
                content.IgnoreUnknownValues = true;
                content.SkipInvalidRows = true;

                var insertTask = service.Tabledata.InsertAll(content, projectId, datasetId, tableId);
                TableDataInsertAllResponse response = insertTask.Execute();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }


        }
    }
}
```

In program.cs:

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            StreamDatacs sd = new StreamDatacs();
            sd.ReadData(@"C:\2015071600.csv");   
            Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            sw.Stop();
            Console.Read();

        }
```

In the code, I read the file line by line, stop and insert into BQ at every 20,000 lines until all the lines has been inserted.I have tried different buffer size (500 lines,1000 lines,50,000 lines) here, but did not see a big difference.
I appreciate any suggestion from you. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since streaming has a limited payload size, see [Quota policy](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery) it's easier to talk about times, as the payload is limited in the same way to both of us, but I will mention other side effects too.

You need to implement the limits properly:

- Maximum row size: 1 MB
- HTTP request size limit: 10 MB
- Maximum rows per request: 500

otherwise you will get errors. Thus it's called streaming insert, so you can run a lot of parallel processes and not one big job.

We measure between 1200-2500 ms for each streaming request, and this was consistent over the last month as you can see in the chart.

[image]

We seen several side effects although:

- the request randomly fails with type 'Backend error'
- the request randomly fails with type 'Connection error'
- the request randomly fails with type 'timeout' (watch out here, as only some rows are failing and not the whole payload)
- some other error messages are non descriptive, and they are so vague that they don't help you, just retry.
- we see hundreds of such failures each day, so they are pretty much constant, and not related to Cloud health.

For all these we opened cases in paid Google Enterprise Support, but unfortunately they didn't resolved it. It seams the recommended option to take for these is an exponential-backoff with retry, even the support told to do so. Which personally doesn't make me happy.

---

The approach you've chosen if takes hours that  means `it does not scale`, and won't scale. You need to rethink the approach with `async processes`. In order to finish sooner, you need to run in parallel multiple workers, the streaming performance will be the same. Just having 10 workers in parallel it means time will be 10 times less.

Processing in background IO bound or cpu bound tasks is now a common practice in most web applications. There's plenty of software to help build background jobs, some based on a messaging system like [Beanstalkd](http://kr.github.io/beanstalkd/).

Basically, you needed to distribute insert jobs across a closed network, to prioritize them, and consume(run) them. Well, that's exactly what Beanstalkd provides.

Beanstalkd gives the possibility to organize jobs in tubes, each tube corresponding to a job type.

You need an API/producer which can put jobs on a tube, let's say a json representation of the row. This was a killer feature for our use case. So we have an API which gets the rows, and places them on tube, this takes just a few milliseconds, so you could achieve fast response time.

On the other part, you have now a bunch of jobs on some tubes. You need an agent. An agent/consumer can reserve a job.

It helps you also with job management and retries: When a job is successfully processed, a consumer can delete the job from the tube. In the case of failure, the consumer can bury the job. This job will not be pushed back to the tube, but will be available for further inspection.

A consumer can release a job, Beanstalkd will push this job back in the tube, and make it available for another client.

Beanstalkd clients can be found in most common languages, a [web interface](https://github.com/ptrofimov/beanstalk_console) can be useful for debugging.

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation for the error handling and job monitoring application. However, what I am really worrying now is the speed of the stream insert. I have to insert sets of memory buffer(2~3GB) to Bigquery in within 10 mins, but I have got 20 mins to process 1 buffer(which is 300MB).This is totally unacceptable for my case. Also I did chunk the file into small pieces and it does not give me a big difference. I just want to make sure if there is the problem in my code(like the chunk size, the way of stream insert, etc) or it is the way Bigquery does.

Comment: Parallelize the calls, I don't see any concurrency there. You should run at least 50 calls in parallel

Comment: I have run into a similar issue, streaming data to bigquery is *extremely* slow (2KB per second!)